# Как подгонять под размер рамки изображение не изменяя его пропорций?

Tags: html, css, изображения

Есть следующая рамка 4x3 для изображений:

```css
.image {
  width: 100%;
}

.image .image-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  padding: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.image .image-wrapper.service {
  margin: 5px auto;
  height: 180px;
  width: 240px;
}

.image .image-wrapper img {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <div class="image-wrapper service">
    <img src="//via.placeholder.com/100x200" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="image">
  <div class="image-wrapper service">
    <img src="//via.placeholder.com/100x100" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="image">
  <div class="image-wrapper service">
    <img src="//via.placeholder.com/200x100" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Но тут такая ситуация что если изображение меньше, то он центруется, а если больше то подгоняется под пропорции.

Как мне сделать так чтобы маленькие изображения внутри рамки увеличились и подогнались под размер заданной 4x3 рамки **не изменив пропорции**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо задать картинкам ширину и высоту блока, потом задать для их фона поведение.

```
.image .image-wrapper img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

И не забывай задать контейнеру правильный размер.

Comment: Сейчас попробую

Comment: Мне нужен был не `cover`, а `contain`)) Решил проблему!))) спасибо) То что надо!

Answer (score 0):

Повесил на `:hover` увеличение.

```css
.image {
  width: 100%;
}

.image .image-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  padding: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.image .image-wrapper.service {
  margin: 5px auto;
  height: 180px;
  width: 240px;
}

.image .image-wrapper img {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.image-wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image-wrapper img {
  transition: .2s;
}

.image-wrapper:hover img {
  transform: scale(2);
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <div class="image-wrapper service">
    <img src="//via.placeholder.com/100x200" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="image">
  <div class="image-wrapper service">
    <img src="//via.placeholder.com/100x100" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="image">
  <div class="image-wrapper service">
    <img src="//via.placeholder.com/200x100" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Я не хочу чтобы изображение обрезалось, надо просто подогнать под рамку, с большими изображениями всё ок, но с маленькими нет

Comment: Ну так отредактируйте вопрос. Я как понял так и ответил.

Comment: Да, согласен, чуток не правильно вопрос был задан, но тот кто ответил правильно понял чего я хотел, и уже на вопрос ответили, спасибо вам

Comment: Эгоизм. ))) Отредактируйте, для тех кто будет после вас искать ответ на такой же вопрос.

Comment: Дак уже сделал после вашего комментария)